# Starting unrelated Celery task within a task in a chord

Tags: celery

I'm new to celery and am doubtless missing the obvious, but how do I start a celery some_worker_task within another celery some_other_task that should execute entirely independent of some_other_task?  In particular, I have a celery chord

```
junk = chord((task_create_syslog_records.s(syslog, user, syslog.fileset_id)
              for syslog in syslog_queryset),
             task_create_syslog_records_done_email.si(user, len(syslog_queryset), syslog_queryset[0].fileset_id))()
```

Under some conditions within one of the task_create_syslog_records I need to start another task, do_some_stuff, unrelated to the chord.  It can run completely independent of the chord and it's result is NOT needed/wanted by the chord.  The chord should complete and task_create_syslog_records_done_email run even if do_some_stuff is still running.

Comment: Why don't you just call that tasks inside of `task_create_syslog_records` implementation ?

Comment: Now I'm doing do_some_stuff.delay(records).  The task runs but it seems to be part of the chord group!  That is task_create_syslog_records_done_email **does not run until after do_some_stuff completes.**  How should I be starting do_some_stuff?

Answer (score 0):

You can create another celery task within existing task:

```
@app.task
def do_some_stuff():
    pass

@app.task
def task_create_syslog_records(syslog, user, filset_id):
    # ...    
    if condition_is_matched:
        do_some_stuff.delay()
    # ...
    return result
```

Comment: That is what I'm doing.  Unfortunately, for whatever reason, the chord's completion task (task_create_syslog_records_done_email) does **not execute until after do_some_stuff** completes.  It is as though do_some_stuff becomes part of the chord. Is there some option that needs to be used?